# TextformFiled Under the Keyboard when parrent widget is Stack

Tags: google-maps, flutter, keyboard

I am using Stack widget as a parent widget. inside the stack widget array, the first widget is a google map and the second widget is TextFormField and I need to set search bar bellow the screen so I use Positioned widget and set below

```
          Scaffold(
  extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  drawer: Drawer(),
  appBar: CommonWidgets.appbar(true),
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
          child: GoogleMap(
              mapType: MapType.terrain,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              compassEnabled: true,
              tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5),
              // markers: Set.from(model.allmarkers),
              initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                //     model.mapController.complete(controller);
              })),
      Positioned(
          bottom: 30,
          left: 40,
          right: 40,
          child: TextFormField(
              controller: searchController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Please enter your ",
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  fillColor: Colors.amber,
                  filled: true)))
    ],
  ),
);
```

Now when I use the keyboard to type, my Search bar does not appear above the soft-keyboard. I think as I set in Positioned widget which is fixing the search bar and don't move it. How to solve this problem. I can't use any other widget except Stack because it is a map screen and everything need to show above the map.

[image: Map Screen]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `Scaffold`'s `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to `true`

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
```

Comment: you are right, but it doesn't work, still, the widget is under the keyboard

Comment: do you mean the `TextFormField` still goes under the keyboard?

Comment: strange. I tried it out with only one change an `Image` widget instead of the map, and it works great. The `TextFormField` comes up along with the keyboard.

Comment: just replace your image with a container having full size and width of screen. and it should be the first element of stack.i.e Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            color: Colors.green,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          )

Comment: Already had `Image` widget of full size, but tried it with full size `Container` like you suggested. And still works great for me. The `TextFormField` moves up fine along with the keyboard. Don't know why it has different behavior for both of us.

Comment: it is strange. wait let me share with you exactly what I have written.

Comment: here is link  you can past and check.(https://gist.github.com/MuhammamdArslanKhan/70c9b2d2171c5768dae50215dbcc33bd)

Comment: I see you have replaced the map with an `Icon` widget of size 800. Tried exactly the same code. Still works great.

Comment: I change the device and run on emulator still same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218419/discussion-between-jigar-patel-and-m-arslankhan).